# Was Jesus completely masculine?

Tags: life-of-jesus, sexuality

Does Jesus have a penis? Does any commentator tell about Jesus' penis?

Is Jesus a man? What is the proof that he is a man?

Is he gay or asexual? Did Jesus experience any sexual feelings?

Did Jesus marry anyone?

Comment: See Matthew 1:25 and Luke 2:7. These describe the birth of Jesus, noting that he was a boy.

Comment: Why is there any doubt? What research prompted the question?

Comment: @Lesley Please note that OP appears, from his icon, to be an Indian gentleman and his question may be prompted by the concept of asexual embodiment of  Hindu deities.

Comment: @Lesley From my conversation [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123218/discussion-between-john-and-4castle), there also appears to be a language and culture barrier about the meaning of "man" and "gay." The question was not worded quite right.

Comment: I was going to edit this to try to make sense out of it...but I don't think it's actually possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Luke 2:21-24** documents that Jesus was circumcised on the 8th day after his birth, and his parents offered a sacrifice at the temple which is necessary for a firstborn son, according to the Law of Moses.

> **21** After eight days, when it was time to circumcise him, he was named Jesus, the name given by the angel before he was conceived.
> **22** Also, when the time came for purifying them according to the Law of Moses, they brought him up to Jerusalem to present him to Jehovah, **23** just as it is written in Jehovah’s Law: “Every firstborn male must be called holy to Jehovah.” **24** And they offered a sacrifice according to what is said in the Law of Jehovah: “a pair of turtledoves or two young pigeons.”

Circumcision implies that Jesus was male and had a penis. The Bible as a whole is completely consistent about this, always using male pronouns and referring to him as a man and son. There's no doubt that there was any abnormality in this regard.

The Bible does not mention Jesus having a wife. Jesus taught that if a person can make room to remain single for the sake of God's Kingdom, he should remain single and not get married. (Matthew 19:10-12) Jesus set a good example for single people in this matter.

Comment: Do Jesus as any sexual feeling

Comment: Probably. I don't have any reason to think that he didn't. He certainly didn't sin though.

Comment: Sexuality is sin

Comment: @John No, that's not in the Bible. God made humans with a sexual desire so that they would marry and have children and accomplish his purpose for humans to fill the earth. God did not create humans to be sinful.

Comment: Many people are telling that Jesus do not have sexual feeling on women for that he is guy

Comment: @John I don't know what you mean by "guy". "Guy" is just an informal word meaning "man".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123218/discussion-between-john-and-4castle).